# How to restore DatabricksRoot(FileStore) data after workspace is decommissioned?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

My Azure Databricks workspace was decommissioned. I forgot to copy files stored in the DatabricksRoot storage (dbfs:/FileStore/...).

Can the workspace be recommissioned/restored? Is there any way to get my data back?

Comment: Try to open MS support ticket

Comment: Thanks Alex. Will do that and update what I learn here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the end-user cannot restore Databricks Workspace.

It can be done by raising support ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/)

It is best practice not to store any data elements in the root Azure Blob storage that is used for root DBFS access for the workspace. The root DBFS storage is not supported for production customer data. However, you might store other objects such as libraries, configuration files, init scripts, and similar data. Either develop an automated process to replicate these objects or remember to have processes in place to update the secondary deployment for manual deployment.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/disaster-recovery#general-best-practices